# Align twinx tick marks

Tags: python, matplotlib, twinx

Is it possible to make a plot with two independent y-axes such that the tick marks align?

Below is an example of half of the solution. I've doubled the y-axis using `twinx`, but the tick marks aren't aligned and the gridlines form an awkward pattern on the plot. Is there a way to make the tick marks share the same positions, but correspond to different y-values? In the example below, I would like the tick mark for 5 on the left to be at the same vertical position as the tick mark for 6 on the right.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.normal(10, 3, size=20)
b = np.random.normal(20, 5, size=40)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax1.hist(a)
ax2.hist(b)
```

[image: histograms]

The overarching point of this exercise is to make the grid lines overlap for the two axes.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to manually set the `yticks` as it stands these are automatically calculated resulting in a variation. Adding something like this:

```
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(ax1.get_ybound()[0], ax1.get_ybound()[1], 5))
ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(ax2.get_ybound()[0], ax2.get_ybound()[1], 5))
```

where we set the `ytick` locations using an array of 5 points between the bounds of the axis. Since  you have a histogram you could just set the lower value to zero in each case, and you may want to have the upper bound somewhat larger, so I would instead have

```
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, ax1.get_ybound()[1]+1, 5))
ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(0, ax2.get_ybound()[1]+1, 5))
```

Giving a plot (with a change of color and transparency (alpha) for clarity):

[image]

Comment: Since the bounds are always defined by two numbers (unless undefined), the following also creates 5 points between the already defined bounds of the axis: `ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(*ax1.get_ybound(),5)`.

Comment: @HAL9001, there is a closing parenthesis missing in your suggestion. It should be: `ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(*ax1.get_ybound(),5))`.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is old, but this might help some people in the future.

I made a function based on the solution above that makes sure that the labels don't end up to be something with a lot of decimals:

```
def calculate_ticks(ax, ticks, round_to=0.1, center=False):
    upperbound = np.ceil(ax.get_ybound()[1]/round_to)
    lowerbound = np.floor(ax.get_ybound()[0]/round_to)
    dy = upperbound - lowerbound
    fit = np.floor(dy/(ticks - 1)) + 1
    dy_new = (ticks - 1)*fit
    if center:
        offset = np.floor((dy_new - dy)/2)
        lowerbound = lowerbound - offset
    values = np.linspace(lowerbound, lowerbound + dy_new, ticks)
    return values*round_to
```

Which is used the following way:

```
ax1.set_yticks(calculate_ticks(ax1, 10))
ax2.set_yticks(calculate_ticks(ax2, 10))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Adding belatedly to the answers: for those who have both negative and positive values in their plots, the solution I have found is as follows:

```
max1 = np.nanmax(ax1.get_ybound()) #in case you have nan values
max2 = np.nanmax(ax2.get_ybound())
nticks = 5 #or other odd number
ax1.set_yticks(np.linspace(-max1, max1, nticks))
ax2.set_yticks(np.linspace(-max2, max2, nticks))
```

This results in symmetrical axis distances from zero, with the zero "line" on the y-axes aligned.

The difficulty with `set_yticks` is that it calculates between `min` and `max`, rather than `min`, `0`, `max`.