# major ticks with locator_params

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I cannot display the major ticks of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd y-axis at the same level. If you have a look at the figure below one can see that:

- y-left axis has 10  bins (grid on)
- 1st y-right axis has only 7 bins and its major ticks are not aligned 
  with those of y-left axis
- 2nd y-right axis has only 9 bins and its major ticks are not aligned with neither the ones of y-left axis or 1st y-right axis.

I had found topics here that suggest to use "locator_parameters":

```
    plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=10)
```

but I haven't manage to make it work in my case. I want to have 10 bins for all y-axis and I want the major ticks to be aligned.

[image]

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib import rcParams
    %matplotlib inline
    x = np.random.rand(20)
    y1 = x*5
    y2 = x*5 + 0.2
    y3 = x*x*3.5 + 0.2*x
    y4 = x*5 + 0.2*x
    yLimMin = 0
    yLimMax = 2.1
    lineWidth = 1.0
    fontSize = 24
    subTitle = ""

    plt.rcParams.update({'axes.labelsize': 'small'})
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(21,29.7))
    ax11 = fig.add_subplot(411)

    subplotAdjustRight = 0.90
    mks = 19 # marker step
    ax11.plot(x,y1, linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color = 'k',
      marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
      label="CO")
    ax11.set_ylabel('CO [%]', color='k')
    plt.ylim((0,5))
    fig.suptitle(subTitle, fontsize = fontSize)
    ax11.yaxis.grid()
    ax11.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=10)
    ax12=ax11.twinx()
    ax12.plot(x,y2,linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color='r',
      marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
      label="CO22")
    ax12.set_ylabel('NO [%]', color='r')
    plt.ylim((0,13))
    ax12.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=10)

    ax13= ax11.twinx()
    rspine = ax13.spines['right']
    rspine.set_position(('axes', 1.05))
    ax13.set_frame_on(True)
    ax13.plot(x,y3,linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color='m',
      marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
      label="CO222")
    ax13.set_ylabel('O [%] ', color='m')
    plt.ylim((0,22))
    ax13.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=10)
```

Comment: What does "at the same level" mean? Please spend more then half a sentence on the actual problem you have.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have added more info to my problem.

Comment: I see. Would [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037386/trouble-aligning-ticks-for-matplotlib-twinx-axes) help?

Comment: Thanks,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243683/matplotlib-align-twinx-tick-marks?rq=1 helped as I need to loop over the plot and create more than 100 figures. Still have to check tomorow on my whole  data, but it seems to work on this example.

Answer (score 1):

ax14.set_yticks(np.linspace(ax14.get_ybound()[0], ax14.get_ybound()[1], 11))

```
x = np.random.rand(20)
y1 = x*5
y2 = x*5 + 0.2
y3 = x*x*3.5 + 0.2*x
y4 = x*5 + 0.2*x
#from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator
yLimMin = 0
yLimMax = 2.1
lineWidth = 1.0
fontSize = 24
subTitle = ""


plt.rcParams.update({'axes.labelsize': 'small'})
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(21,29.7))
ax11 = fig.add_subplot(411)

subplotAdjustRight = 0.90
mks = 19 # marker step
#matplotlib.locator.MAXTICKS = 5
ax11.plot(x,y1, linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color = 'k',
                     marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
                     label="CO")
ax11.set_ylabel('CO [%]', color='k')
plt.ylim((0,5))
fig.suptitle(subTitle, fontsize = fontSize)
ax11.yaxis.grid()
#ax11.locator_params(axis='ax11', nbins=10)
ax11.set_yticks(np.linspace(ax11.get_ybound()[0], ax11.get_ybound()[1], 11))

ax12=ax11.twinx()
ax12.plot(x,y2,linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color='r',
                marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
                label="CO22")
ax12.set_ylabel('NO [%]', color='r')
plt.ylim((0,13))
#ax12.locator_params(axis='ax11', nbins=10)
ax12.set_yticks(np.linspace(ax12.get_ybound()[0], ax12.get_ybound()[1], 11))

ax13= ax11.twinx()
rspine = ax13.spines['right']
rspine.set_position(('axes', 1.05))
ax13.set_frame_on(True)
ax13.plot(x,y3,linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color='m',
                marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
                label="CO222")
ax13.set_ylabel('O [%] ', color='m')
plt.ylim((0,22.87))
#ax13.locator_params(axis='ax11', nbins=10)
ax13.set_yticks(np.linspace(ax13.get_ybound()[0], ax13.get_ybound()[1], 11))

ax14= ax11.twinx()
rspine = ax14.spines['right']
rspine.set_position(('axes', 1.10))
ax14.set_frame_on(True)
ax14.plot(x,y4,linestyle='-', linewidth=lineWidth, color='m',
                marker='*', markevery=11*mks, 
                label="CO2")
ax14.set_ylabel('CO [%] ', color='m')
plt.ylim((0,25))
#ax14.locator_params(axis='ax11', nbins=10)
ax14.set_yticks(np.linspace(ax14.get_ybound()[0], ax14.get_ybound()[1], 11))
```